# Apple VPP apps asking for user's password when updating applications

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, volume-purchase-program

I've got an issue with a pilot deployment of iPhones with VPP device licences assigned. These are iPhone 11s, running iOS 13.3, managed via a MDM solution that pushes VPP **device** licences to DEP managed devices that are enrolled into the MDM.

All sets up well and fine, and the user can take a fully deployed iPhone and sign into the MDM solution's management app, and then the Apple App Store works just fine. All the apps we push appear as expected and the iPhones work as expected.

However, some users are prompted daily for their (managed company) Apple ID if any application updates are pending for the apps that were pushed to their phone using VPP (Just to be clear, the user is being asked for their own managed Apple ID, not another person's Apple ID or the VPP token details).

It looks like this is related to automatic app updates, as these prompts cease if this is turned off in iPhone Settings app → iCloud → iTunes & App Store → Automatic Downloads → App Updates.

Expected behaviour should be to update the apps without the user having to sign in again.

Note that the VPP apps are correctly licenced to the device, and its possible to deploy a device, hand it to a user who does not sign in to the App Store, and app updates are pushed just fine.

Comment: This could likely be a bug in iOS. I'd start by reporting it to Apple first using the [Bug Reporting - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/). However, it may take a while before your bug report may get acknowledged. If you also have any alternate channel to reach someone within Apple, you can leverage it and request to be pointed in the appropriate direction with much quicker and assured response.

Comment: Are users allowed to setup iCloud and also login to their personal Apple ID on these devices?

Comment: @NimeshNeema I agree. Our MDM vendor have been investigating and don’t think it’s *their* bug and can’t see any config errors on my part in either their product or ABM.

Comment: @icondaemon users are allowed to do this but we have reproduced this error on devices where this has not happened.

Comment: So ... on iDevices where iCloud/Apple IDs are _not_ configured, users are still prompted for their personal Apple IDs?

Comment: @IconDaemon  if a user does not sign in then they are not prompted at all. When you say "personal Apple ID", I'm assuming you're talking about signing out of the managed *appleid@company.com* address we've issued and signing in as *person@gmail.com*? Where no one is signed in to the device at all, no prompts. When user signs in with company-issued AppleID, some users are prompted some are not, seemingly at random.

Comment: Ah. A little clarification is needed in your question when you write about _their own Apple ID_ which to me implies their personal Apple ID is in use.

Comment: I've modified the question @IconDaemon and hopefully it's clearer now. I don't think it should make any difference though, as the VPP licences are licenced per device and not per user, so they're not assigned to the user's Apple ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else experiences a similar issue, I've just had a discussion with Apple and they have confirmed this is an issue in iOS 13 and that it is fixed in iOS 13.3.1